# Passing date parameters to OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue where I am trying to pass parameters to a T-SQL `OPENROWSET` command. I keep getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

When I run the `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET` directly, without using the `EXEC @laborquery` command, it works. I'm thinking it's some sort of syntax error in the way I am passing in the  **`@lastModifiedBeginDate`** and **`@lastModifiedEndDate`** parameters.

The **`timesheet_date`** field I am **`SELECT`** is a `char(10)` field, and I have no way to change this.

```
DECLARE @lastModifiedBeginDate smalldatetime = 2014-12-01
DECLARE @lastModifiedEndDate  smalldatetime = getdate()
DECLARE @laborquery varchar(max)

SET @laborquery ='SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', 
                                           ''Server=zzz;Database=yyy;Trusted_Connection=yes;Integrated_Security=SSPI'', 
    ''SELECT 
        a.company_code AS company_code, 
        a.employee_or_equipment_id AS employee_or_equipment_id, 
        a.timesheet_date as timesheet_date, 
    FROM  Allocated_Time a   
    INNER JOIN Company_Location b 
    ON B.company_code = A.company_code 
    WHERE work_unit_Id 
        IN (''10051862'',   ''10051863'',   ''10051868'',   ''10051959'', ''10051979'', ''10080220'')  
      AND CAST(timesheet_date AS smalldatetime) BETWEEN ' +  @lastModifiedBeginDate + ' AND ' +  @lastModifiedEndDate +  ' AND B.location=1'')'
EXEC @laborquery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Parenthesis` around `@laborquery` in `exec`

```
EXEC (@laborquery)
```

and you need to add some more `quotes` and convert your variables to `varchar`

```
SET @laborquery ='SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=zzz;Database=yyy;Trusted_Connection=yes;Integrated_Security=SSPI'', ''SELECT 
    a.company_code AS company_code, 
    a.employee_or_equipment_id AS employee_or_equipment_id, 
    a.timesheet_date as timesheet_date, 
    FROM  Allocated_Time a   
    INNER JOIN Company_Location b 
    ON B.company_code = A.company_code 
    WHERE work_unit_Id 
    IN (10051862,   10051863,   10051868,   10051959, 10051979, 10080220)  
    AND CAST(timesheet_date AS smalldatetime) BETWEEN ''''' +  
    convert(varchar(30),@lastModifiedBeginDate) + ''''' AND ''''' +  
    convert(varchar(30),@lastModifiedEndDate ) +  ''''' AND B.location=1'')'
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I no longer get the error, but it's not obeying the BETWEEN command. I'm getting data before December 1st, 2014.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the last piece of the puzzle is that 2014-12-01 is not a date constant. It's actually a sum involving integers, 2014 - 12 - 1 = 2001. 2001 is the internal value for the 25th June 1905. Put single quotes around your date constants.

Comment: I just barely figured this out, as I was seeing the 25th June 1905 value as well. Thanks so much.